# What do <> (angle brackets) mean in Google Sheet formulas?

Tags: google-sheets

What does `<>` mean in a spreadsheet formula, such as:

```
=A1<>B1
```

Answer (score 1):

`<>` is the [not equal operator](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093981?hl=en).

`=A1<>B1` evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on if the values of A1 and B1 are equal.  It is the same as `=NE(A1, B1)`